# MongoDB: $project with $filter, include all other attributes

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using a MongoDB aggregate query that contains a `$project` stage containing a `$filter` operator:

```
[
    '$project' => [
        'array' => [
            '$filter' => [
                'input' => '$array',
                'as' => 'array',
                'cond' => [
                    '$in' => [
                        "value",
                        '$$array.subarray'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

This filters out all the array elements that don't have a certain value in a subarray.

While this works as intended, this also removes all other fields from the aggregate query, and only passes the array field to the next stage. How can I tell the `$project` stage to not remove any other fields besides filtering those array elements?

I have read that excluding a single field causes inclusion of all other fiels, but besides that I don't have a field that I want to exclude, I can't add an exclude operation to this `$project` stage, since the `$filter` operation already acts as an input operation, and you can't mix the two. Any ideas?

Comment: use $addFields instead of $project

Comment: Can I filter array elements with addFields?

Comment: everything stays the same except addFields keeps all the existing fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `$addFields` aggregation stage instead of `$project`. The [`$addFields` manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) reads:

> The $addFields stage is equivalent to a $project stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.

Therefore it is sufficient to replace `$project` by `$addFields` in the code in order to archieve the desired behaviour.

This was suggested by @Veeram in the comments.